# Native Query Fetches No Results

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The below JPA Native query always returns '0' (no results), however we have records for this condition in the DB.

Can someone please advise what we are doing wrong here?

```
List<Integer> intArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
intArrayList.add(10);
intArrayList.add(20);

String col3Vals = "'test1','test2'";

Query qry = entityMgr.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from mytable where col1 = ?1 and col2 in ?2 and col3 in (?3)")
.setParameter(1, "testVal")
.setParameter(2, intArrayList);
.setParameter(3, col3Vals);
List<?> res = qry.getResultList();
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code like below resolved the issue, the issue was with the way how we populated the String values for column 'col3' that we had in one of the 'IN' clauses.

```
List<Integer> intArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
intArrayList.add(10);
intArrayList.add(20);

List<String> stringVals = new ArrayList<>();
stringVals.add("test1");
stringVals.add("test2");

Query qry = entityMgr.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from mytable where col1 = ?1 and col2 in ?2 and col3 in ?3")
.setParameter(1, "testVal")
.setParameter(2, intArrayList);
.setParameter(3, stringVals);
List<?> res = qry.getResultList();
```